# Videos uploaded by a specific user Youtube

Tags: android, youtube-api

I want to play certain youtube channel's videos using media player. I have used the [following API](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads) to get the feed. I got the url but mediaplayer says "failed to play". The below is the url tried to play

```
http://o-o---preferred---sn-h557snes---v24---lscache3.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?upn=AmmxhSpq470&sparams=cp,gcr,id,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&fexp=917013,906437,916626,922401,920704,912806,927201,925706,922403,913546,913556,916805,920201,901451&ms=au&expire=1353668177&itag=18&ipbits=8&gcr=in&sver=3&ratebypass=yes&mt=1353646087&ip=121.241.181.70&mv=m&source=youtube&key=yt1&cp=U0hUSFZRVl9MUUNONF9OS1pCOmhtUTVMak5oTVNy&id=c429fa5466ee9447&newshard=yes
```

Is there any changes in decoding format?Please help me..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one of the official YouTube players to play back YouTube content. For Android applications right now, that means embedding the [iframe player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) within a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) in your application.

At some point in the future, we'll be releasing a [native Android YouTube player](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/120/) view that you can embed in your applications, but I don't have any information to share about the release date.

Comment: But I have already tried with Android media player.. It was working..But now it is not working for some other reasons.Is there any changes in decoding format?

Comment: There are low-resolution RTSP streams exposed publicly for some videos, but not all of them. It's up to the content owner to determine whether they're exposed or not. Maybe that's what you mean? Here's an example: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/RWiBAHv7sXs?v=2&alt=json&prettyprint=true&fields=media:group/media:content[@yt:format=1]